# Move the zoom-in/zoom-out to another place than upper-left corner

Tags: vue-component

When using Vue2Leaflet and the "l-map" component, is there a way to move the zoom-in/zoom-out buttons to another place than upper-left corner?

https://vue-leaflet.github.io/Vue2Leaflet/#/components/l-map/?id=props

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITRFr.png

Answer (score 0):

You need disable the default zoom controls first. Then add LControlZoom component with your preferred position. like-

```
<l-control-zoom position="bottomleft"></l-control-zoom>
```

HTML:

```
<template>
 <l-map style="height: 350px" :zoom="zoom" :center="center" :options="{zoomControl: false}">
    <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
    <l-control-zoom position="bottomleft"></l-control-zoom>
 </l-map>
```

in javaScript

```
<script>
import {LMap, LTileLayer, LControlZoom} from 'vue2-leaflet';

export default {
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LControlZoom
  },
  data () {
    return {
      url: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      zoom: 8,
      center: [47.313220, -1.319482],
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps. Read here vue2-leaflet documentation : https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.com/components/LControlZoom.html